# Migrate entire registry key during installation with WiX

Tags: wix

I have a WiX-based installer and I would like to make it automatically migrate all values from one registry key to another.

That is, any values found under `HKLM\Software\MyCompany\MyProduct\SomeOldSetting` should be copied to `HKLM\Software\MyCompany\MyProduct\SomeNewSetting`

The values found under the key are dynamically generated and so I can't just write installer logic to migrate the individual values.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll want to write a custom action that reads the existing keys then add temporary rows to the `Registry` and `RemoveRegistry` table. The Windows Installer will take care of writing the new keys and removing the old keys all in a nice compensating transaction.

Comment: For example, see https://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/07/01/semi-custom-actions/.